# How to create my first menu in Laravel Nova using nova-menu-builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a fresh installation of Laravel 8, Nova, and the nova-menu-builder package and I'm trying to create my first menu.

But when I try to create, it asks me to provide a menu from a dropdown that is empty.

Do you know how to overcome this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from the author of the package here.
The documentation was missing this part.
https://github.com/optimistdigital/nova-menu-builder/issues/63#issuecomment-702554059

I had to define the list of available menus in the config file.
See nova-menu.php, key named menus.